# Pass data from modal to another page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to pass data from modal to another page. Could you please help me to accomplish this task?

```
 $scope.productdetails = function (size,selectedproduct)
     {       
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({           
    templateUrl: 'ProductDetails.html',            
    controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, product) {
        $scope.product = product;

        $scope.buynow = function (path) {
            $uibModalInstance.close($scope.product);
            $location.path(path); // Need to pass $scope.product to the new page
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    },
    size: size,
    resolve: {
        product: function () {
            return selectedproduct;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Use a service to share dta between different parts of app

Comment: Brian Hann outlines one method on his site, which I use almost exclusively myself: http://brianhann.com/pass-data-to-a-ui-bootstrap-modal-without-scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to read the docs on `$uibModal`: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs

the `open()` method will return an object with some useful stuff in it. Currently you're not doing anything with that object, but that's where the magic is.

To pass data to the controller that opened the modal, use the `modalInstance.result` promise like this:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(data) { /*... do something with the data*/ });
```

Once that is set up, you can use the `$close()` function that this modal library places on the scope to resolve the `result` promise.

```
var data = {info: 'information to be returned to the parent controller'};
$scope.$close(data);
```

Comment: I have written like this,
modalInstance.result.then(function (product) {
            $scope.selectedProduct = product;
            $location.path('cart');            
        });
How should I pass product to the new location path?

Comment: Since you're implementing a shopping cart, I think you should store the user's selection(s) in a cookie, then retrieve that cookie on the 'cart' page.
Cookies are used for that purpose on just about every e-commerce website.